# How to design classes for X number of config files which needs to be read individually in memory?

Tags: go, struct

I am working with lot of config files. I need to read all those individual config file in their own `struct` and then make one giant `Config` struct which holds all other individual config struct in it.

Let's suppose if I am working with 3 config files.

- `ClientConfig` deals with one config file.
- `DataMapConfig` deals with second config file.
- `ProcessDataConfig` deals with third config file.

I created separate class for each of those individual config file and have separate `Readxxxxx` method in them to read their own individual config and return struct back. Below is my `config.go` file which is called via `Init` method from `main` function after passing `path` and `logger`.

**config.go**

```
package config

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/david/internal/utilities"
)

type Config struct {
    ClientMapConfigs   ClientConfig
    DataMapConfigs     DataMapConfig
    ProcessDataConfigs ProcessDataConfig
}

func Init(path string, logger log.Logger) (*Config, error) {
    var err error
    clientConfig, err := ReadClientMapConfig(path, logger)
    dataMapConfig, err := ReadDataMapConfig(path, logger)
    processDataConfig, err := ReadProcessDataConfig(path, logger)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Config{
        ClientMapConfigs:       *clientConfig,
        DataMapConfigs:         *dataMapConfig,
        ProcessDataConfigs:     *processDataConfig,
    }, nil
}
```

**clientconfig.go**

```
package config

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "github.com/david/internal/utilities"
)

type ClientConfig struct {
  .....
  .....
}

const (
    ClientConfigFile = "clientConfigMap.json"
)

func ReadClientMapConfig(path string, logger log.Logger) (*ClientConfig, error) {
  files, err := utilities.FindFiles(path, ClientConfigFile)
  // read all the files
  // do some validation on all those files
  // deserialize them into ClientConfig struct
  // return clientconfig object back
}
```

**datamapconfig.go**

Similar style I have for `datamapconfig` too. Exactly replica of `clientconfig.go` file but operating on different config file name and will return `DataMapConfig` struct back.

**processdataConfig.go**

Same thing as `clientconfig.go` file. Only difference is it will operate on different config file and return `ProcessDataConfig` struct back.

**Problem Statement**

I am looking for ideas where this above design can be improved? Is there any better way to do this in `golang`? Can we use interface or anything else which can improve the above design?

If I have let's say 10 different files instead of 3, then do I need to keep doing above same thing for remaining 7 files? If yes, then the code will look ugly. Any suggestions or ideas will greatly help me.

**Update**

Everything looks good but I have few questions as I am confuse on how can I achieve those with your current suggestion. On majority of my configs, your suggestion is perfect but there are two cases on two different configs where I am confuse on how to do it.

- **Case 1** After deserializing json into original struct which matches json format, I make another different struct after massaging that data and then I return that struct back.
- **Case 2** All my configs have one file but there are few configs which have multiple files in them and the number isn't fixed. So I pass regex file name and then I find all the files starting with that regex and then loop over all those files one by one. After deserializing each json file, I start populating another object and keep populating it until all files have been deserialized and then make a new struct with those objects and then return it.

Example of above scenarios:

**Sample case 1**

```
package config

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "io/ioutil"
  "github.com/david/internal/utilities"
)

type CustomerManifest struct {
  CustomerManifest map[int64]Site
}

type CustomerConfigs struct {
  CustomerConfigurations []Site `json:"customerConfigurations"`
}

type Site struct {
  ....
  ....
}

const (
  CustomerConfigFile = "abc.json"
)

func ReadCustomerConfig(path string, logger log.Logger) (*CustomerManifest, error) {
  // I try to find all the files with my below utility method.
  // Work with single file name and also with regex name
  files, err := utilities.FindFiles(path, CustomerConfigFile)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  var customerConfig CustomerConfigs
  // there is only file for this config so loop will run once
  for _, file := range files {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &customerConfig)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }
  }

  customerConfigIndex := BuildIndex(customerConfig, logger)
  return &CustomerManifest{CustomerManifest: customerConfigIndex}, nil
}

func BuildIndex(customerConfig CustomerConfigs, logger log.Logger) map[int64]Site {
  ...
  ...
}
```

As you can see above in **sample case 1**, I am making `CustomerManifest` struct from `CustomerConfigs` struct and then return it instead of returning `CustomerConfigs` directly.

**Sample case 2**

```
package config

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
  "github.com/david/internal/utilities"
)

type StateManifest struct {
    NotionTemplates       NotionTemplates
    NotionIndex           map[int64]NotionTemplates
}

type NotionMapConfigs struct {
    NotionTemplates      []NotionTemplates      `json:"notionTemplates"`
  ...
}

const (
  // there are many files starting with "state-", it's not fixed number
    StateConfigFile = "state-*.json"
)

func ReadStateConfig(path string, logger log.Logger) (*StateManifest, error) {
  // I try to find all the files with my below utility method.
  // Work with single file name and also with regex name
    files, err := utilities.FindFiles(path, StateConfigFile)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    var defaultTemp NotionTemplates
    var idx = map[int64]NotionTemplates{}

  // there are lot of config files for this config so loop will run multiple times
    for _, file := range files {
        var notionMapConfig NotionMapConfigs
        body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        err = json.Unmarshal(body, &notionMapConfig)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        for _, tt := range notionMapConfig.NotionTemplates {
            if tt.IsProcess {
                defaultTemp = tt
            } else if tt.ClientId > 0 {
                idx[tt.ClientId] = tt
            }
        }
    }

    stateManifest := StateManifest{
        NotionTemplates:       defaultTemp,
        NotionIndex:           idx,
    }
    return &stateManifest, nil
}
```

As you can see above in my both the cases, I am making another different struct after deserializing is done and then I return that struct back but as of now in your current suggestion I think I won't be able to do this generically because for each config I do different type of massaging and then return those struct back. Is there any way to achieve above functionality with your current suggestion? Basically for each config if I want to do some massaging, then I should be able to do it and return new modified struct back but for some cases if I don't want to do any massaging then I can return direct deserialize json struct back. Can this be done generically?

Since there are config which has multiple files in them so that is why I was using my `utilities.FindFiles` method to give me all files basis on file name or regex name and then I loop over all those files to either return original struct back or return new struct back after massaging original struct data.

Comment: Is there really a compelling reason to put the config in 3 files?  Why not one file with 3 sections?  Unmarshal straight into a *Config?  The challenge with multiple files is when they conflict,  then order matters and it can be difficult to know how to combine them

Comment: You'll also want to specify that config path in an env var or parameter, not a const.  You'll need to be setting to some nondefault values in your tests

Comment: @DanielFarrell It's a legacy system and they are huge files so it was designed like that. We can't have one file with all the configs in them. They are not app configs but business related configs so they are kinda big (but not huge as well). They all are independent configs not related to any one other at all so we just need to read all those individual configs separately and put them in one struct.

Comment: Is there a single config file for each struct, or are there multiple files? The code reads like there are multiple. What type of validations do you do? Can you do those validations after unmarshaling?

Comment: It's a mix of both. For most of the cases, it is only single config file which I have to load into a struct. And for one case, there are multiple config files (but still it is one config category) following same json structure and they start with same prefix and I just iterate all those files and load it into a struct. And regarding validations yes I can do after unmarshaling @BurakSerdar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a common function to load all the configuration files.

Assume you have config structures:

```
type Config1 struct {...}
type Config2 struct {...}
type Config3 struct {...}
```

You define configuration validators for those who need it:

```
func (c Config1) Validate() error {...}
func (c Config2) Validate() error {...}
```

Note that these implement a `Validatable` interface:

```
type Validatable interface {
   Validate() error
}
```

There is one config type that includes all these configurations:

```
type Config struct {
   C1 Config1
   C2 Config2
   C3 Config3
   ...
}
```

Then, you can define a simple configuration loader function:

```
func LoadConfig(fname string, out interface{}) error {
    data, err:=ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
    if err!=nil {
       return err
    }
    if err:=json.Unmarshal(data,out); err!=nil {
       return err
    }
    // Validate the config if necessary
    if validator, ok:=out.(Validatable); ok {
       if err:=validator.Validate(); err!=nil {
         return err
       }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Then, you can load the files:

```
var c Config
if err:=LoadConfig("file1",&c.C1); err!=nil {
   return err
}
if err:=LoadConfig("file2",&c.C2); err!=nil {
   return err
}
...
```

If there are multiple files loading different parts of the same struct, you can do:

```
LoadConfig("file1",&c.C3)
LoadConfig("file2",&c.C3)
...
```

You can simplify this further by defining a slice:

```
type cfgInfo struct {
   fileName string
   getCfg func(*Config) interface{}
}

var configs=[]cfgInfo {
   {
     fileName: "file1",
     getCfg: func(c *Config) interface{} {return &c.C1},
   },
   {
     fileName: "file2",
     getCfg: func(c *Config) interface{} {return &c.C2},
   },
   {
     fileName: "file3",
     getCfg: func(c *Config) interface{} {return &c.C3},
   },
   ...
}

func loadConfigs(cfg *Config) error {
   for _,f:=range configs {
     if err:=loadConfig(f.fileName,f.getCfg(cfg)); err!=nil {
         return err
     }
   }
  return nil
}
```

Then, `loadConfigs` would load all the configuration files into `cfg`.

```
func main() {
   var cfg Config
   if err:=loadConfigs(&cfg); err!=nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   ...
}
```

Any configuration that doesn't match this pattern can be dealt with using `LoadConfig`:

```
var customConfig1 CustomConfigStruct1
if err:=LoadConfig("customConfigFile1",&customConfig1); err!=nil {
   panic(err)
}
cfg.CustomConfig1 = processCustomConfig1(customConfig1)

var customConfig2 CustomConfigStruct2
if err:=LoadConfig("customConfigFile2",&customConfig2); err!=nil {
   panic(err)
}
cfg.CustomConfig2 = processCustomConfig2(customConfig2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I think this simplifies things a lot for me. I have few questions as I recently started with Golang so kinda confuse on my end. How will I call `loadConfigs` method? I mean what I am suppose to pass to that method? If you can provide an example from main function then this will clear my doubt. Also can I have separate go file for each config instead of keeping everything in one go file? Like `config1.go` file which will hold `config1` struct and their own `Validate()` method in its own file.

Comment: .. Similarly `config2.go` file which will hold `config2` struct and their own validate method. Similarly for all other configs file. And then `Validatable` interface in its own file maybe?

Comment: I added a main function. You can place each config into its own file.

Comment: Yup make sense now. Sorry I couldn't respond earlier. I have few confusions as I have two cases where I am confuse on how to achieve those with your suggestion. On rest of my configs this looks perfect and it works too. There are cases for me where I deserialize json into a struct and then I make a new struct from that original struct after massaging the data and then return it. How can I do this generically for each config? Some configs will require it and some don't so how can I do that generically? I have updated my question with all the details. Let me know if it isn't clear.

Comment: .. Is there anything that can be added in `cfgInfo` struct so that `loadConfig` can do it generically? or any other better solution?

Comment: If you have other types of configuration where you use an intermediate struct, those are better handled separately. The code to load an unmarshal the struct is minimal. Simply handle those cases as separate cases, there is not much to be gained from trying to abstract away the configuration loading part. The code is minimal.

Comment: yeah I think it makes sense. Problem with me right now is I am working with four different configs for now (eventually it will be around 10 later on) so out of those four, I need to make intermediate struct for 3 of those configs and remaining one is I directly deserialized to original struct and returned back just like your original suggestion so was wondering what can I do to overcome that part. Do you think is there any solution that can be done generically to handle this case? or pretty much need to do it separately as you already said earlier?

Comment: You can still use `LoadConfig` to load those configuration files, using your intermediate structs. So use `loadConfigs` for the common ones, and individual `LoadConfig` calls for the others that need special processing.

Comment: But how will I tell `LoadConfig` for this category of config do these kind of processing and for this category of config, do this kind of processing? I can pass the interface type what I am expecting after massaging the original struct but confusion is the processing part of different configs? How can I make that generic if there is any easy way? or you mean to say I should have different `LoadConfig` method for different category of configs which does their own processing and return modified struct back?

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: Understood. I thought so as well. Make sense now. Let me look into that. Appreciate your help!